# IP and Domain Name Both Are Working AWS Lightsail. How to Fix?

Tags: wordpress, dns, ip, web-hosting, amazon-lightsail

My Website https://www.webseostar.com/ is working with its public IP address http://15.207.30.145/ as well. I have changed A records in Route 53. but nothing is working. Please suggest.

I will be very thankful.

I try changing A records and wait for hours, supposing that it will be fixed. But it doesn't work. I am using Lightsail distribution as well.

[Attached is screenshot of route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHU5R.png)

[Another from Lightsail DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od5hr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have DNS records setup in the Lightsail and Route 53, you may find that the records setup in Lightsail are the ones being published. You can verify this by using https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx to view the published records.

If you find that your DNS records are indeed under the control of Lightsail, follow the migration instructions which would apply to an outside vendor DNS host for a migration to Route 53. In my case, it was a matter of changing the NS records in Lightsail to be the same as the NS records setup by Route 53.  This shifted all DNS control to Route 53.

Carefully record your DNS records in both locations before you start in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I have changed the DNS zone to Route 53, as suggested by you. I don't see any instant impact. The problem is as it is. I waiting for some time. I hope it gets resolved. I will let you know if it get resolved.